# iOS UICircularProgressRing radial gradient

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm using [UICircularProgressRing] library in my `swift 4` project in order to display a `progress circular bar`. The type I'm using is `gradient` and it's not a full circle. The `start angle` is 120 and the `end angle` is 60. I'm facing problem with the `gradient` color. It's not applied as radial. I want to have a gradient starting with the green color, then yellow and finally red. The same as this picture with reversing the first and last color.

[image]

This is what I'm actually having:

[image]

Using this code:

```
func configureRing() {
        ringView.delegate = self
        let green = UIColor(hexString: "#31c8b4")!
        let yellow = UIColor(hexString: "#fbd16a")!
        let red = UIColor(hexString: "#fe160f")!
        ringView.ringStyle = .gradient

        ringView.gradientColors = [green, red]
        ringView.gradientColors = [green, yellow, red]
        ringView.gradientColorLocations = [0, 0.5, 1]
        ringView.gradientStartPosition = UICircularProgressRingGradientPosition.bottomLeft
        ringView.gradientEndPosition = UICircularProgressRingGradientPosition.bottomRight
        ringView.value = 100
    }
```

As you can see, the yellow part is very small.

[UICircularProgressRing] = https://github.com/luispadron/UICircularProgressRing

**Edit:** 
When I add more colors this is what I get:

```
ringView.gradientColors = [green, yellow, yellow, red]
ringView.gradientColorLocations = [0, 0.4, 0.6, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: @matt I want that every color gets 1/3 of the arc

Comment: Okay, so add more colors and locations to specify that. All you are saying right now is "pass briefly thru yellow at the halfway point". So the computer is doing that. It only does what you tell it. If you want more, tell it more.

Comment: @matt see my edit please

Comment: @NeAS Did you solve this issue ? I have this same issue where  I'm providing the circle with 4 colors ( 1/4 for each one) but it's repeating them

Comment: Hi @NeAS. I am having a difficulty setting gradient colors. can you share me your code here in an answer ?

Comment: Hi @NeAS Can you please share me the code for UICircularProgressRing radial gradient. I want to implement the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about UICircularProgressRing, but I do know how to specify a gradient. So, assuming this works in a normal way, you might try something more like:

```
    ringView.gradientColors = [green, yellow, yellow, red]
    ringView.gradientColorLocations = [0, 0.4, 0.6, 1]
```

Tweak the colors and locations as desired, of course. When I do that sort of thing with an ordinary CAGradientLayer, I get this:

[image]

... which seems to distribute the colors along the gradient rather as you are describing.